# Getting value in C# code behind from an asp:DropDownList populated with Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, html-select

I have 2 DropDownLists which are populated in c# code before the page is rendered. When the page is posted back I can successfully get the changed values.  However, one condition is if the value changes in the first DropDownList I repopulate the second drop down list.  I am doing this using an Ajax call and everything is visually working well.

The problem is when the condition arises that the second DropDownList is populated via Ajax code the list items and selected values are not being shown back in the C# code when posted back.  I have read that this will NOT happen.

The DropDownList has an `ID="cboMutations"`

I have finally got this working using the following method:

```
        Int32 id = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$cboMutations"]))
        {
            Int32.TryParse(Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$cboMutations"], out id);
        }
```

My main questions are:

Is this safe to use `ctl00$MainContent$cboMutations` to reference the property in this manner?

It works in development, but will it work when deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net is strict about what data it accepts. An asp drop down list would not allow you to send data like that. This makes sure that users only send values that were presented by the server.

In your case you are using html controls and by passing asp.net's inbuilt security. You should program for the case that malicious users may try to send invalid data using the input `ctl00$MainContent$cboMutations`.

Since you are parsing the data to an int there is little a malicious user could do. You should be safe when deployed too.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.